# How to get the typename of a QObject instance parsing QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I have got a QQuickView which has loaded a qml file like the following.

```
Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100 }
```

Then I am retrieving the root object via `QObject *root = view->rootObject()`.
Now I want to get the class name from this object.
The following code results into "QQuickRectangle"

```
root->metaObject()->className()
```

But what I want is "Rectangle" just like the typename in the qml file.
Any idea?

Edit: I want to build a treeview with the object hirarchie of a qml file like QtCreator.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pattern there, for qml types implemented in C++ the name would be `QQuickSomething`, for qml types implemented in qml the name would be `Something_QMLTYPE_X_MAYBEMORESTUFF(objAddress)`.

So you can do some basic string editing depending on the result you get to isolate the actual type name:

```
QString name = QString(root->metaObject()->className());
if (name.contains("QQuick")) name.remove("QQuick");
else if (name.contains("QMLTYPE")) name.remove(QRegExp("_QMLTYPE_[0-9]*.*"));
// else it might be just a QObject or your on custom type you should handle
```

> Edit: I want to build a treeview with the object hirarchie of a qml
>   file like QtCreator.

Unless you are willing to dig into and use private APIs, it would likely be easier and also more useful to have your own custom model to drive both a view and the actual object tree. Also, QML is quite easy to parse, I'd personally buckle down and write a parses faster than it would take me to get into the existing one, especially if all that is needed is an object tree outline, but YMMV.

Comment: If I have custom QML type, for example `Test.qml` where `Item` is root item, `console.log()` prints it out as `qml: QQuickItem(0x2a63b050)` not as `Test_QMLTYPE_X` so I lose the type in this case. Tested with Qt 5.7.0, MinGW.

Comment: The C++ classname and the QML type name don't need to have any relation.
`qmlRegisterType()` takes an arbitrary string (as long as it is a valid type name) as its fourth argument

Comment: @folibis - that's odd, for me it always prints the QMLTYPE regardless of what the root item is and how it is implemented.

Comment: @KevinKrammer - that is true, however stock qml types follow the same convention. And I don't see any good reason not to follow it for your own types as well. And without a public api to access qml meta data directly there doesn't seem to be much else you can do. That's one of the things about Qt that sucks big time IMO - too much important stuff is either private, hardcoded or missing altogether.

Comment: Right, you could have your own class naming scheme and check for that additionally to the one used by `QQuick`. But that only solves your classes and `QQuick` classes, not for of any third party.

Comment: @KevinKrammer - who uses 3rd party ;) But even so, you could build a simple registry containing the various type collections in use. It would be nice if there was a better way...

Comment: @ddriver sure that would be doable, but it is just a workaround. Since this is tooling, it could just be using the same hooks other tooling is using, e.g. QtCreator, or add hooks if not present yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is "better" information kept on this (`QQmlType` & `QQmlMetaType`), but it is not accessible through any public API that I can think of.

Can you explain what you would like to do with it? Maybe there's an alternative.

Comment: I am working on a qml designer app and I want to fill a treeview like the navigator from QtCreator. Maybe there is a qml-parser out there?

Comment: QtQuick's own parser is at https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/tree/dev/src/qml/parser. From what I remember, I think Creator uses a copy of that, adapted for itself - but I don't know much about Creator so I may be wrong.

The .g file would probably be a good place to start for looking at the "rules".

Answer (score 0):

QtQuick doesn't provide some special metadata for QML items. It looks that QtQuick uses item types internally only while parsing the source.
The known workaround is `objectName`:

```
Rectangle {
    objectName: "Rectangle"
}
```

and so:

```
QString className = item->objectName();
```

Comment: Are you sure about that. `console.log(someObj)` appears to indicate otherwise. Also `objectName` is implemented all the way back in `QObject` so it can be accessed directly rather than the much slower string lookup property plus variant conversion.

Comment: Yes, `console.log()` prints out metainfo of C++ object like all other Qt classes derived from `QObject`, in this case `QQuickRectangle`, exactly like `metaObject()->className()` does that. You cannot get QML type name, like `Item`, `Rectangle` or `MyItem`

Comment: For qml defined types, for my `T_Root.qml` type the console output says `T_Root_QMLTYPE_18` so there evidently is qml type information.